# Canvas aligning lines to linear-gradient color stops

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have been trying to create ticks between each division of my linear gradient, for some reason I can not get them to align properly with the gradient, the math is pretty simple yet it is still off by a few pixels in very big gradients.

My HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="canvas.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        canvas {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1300" height="300"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

canvas.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var canvas= $("canvas")[0];
    var canvasWidth= $("canvas").innerWidth();
    var canvasHeight= $("canvas").innerHeight();
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var size= [0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight/2];

    var grad = ctx.createLinearGradient(size[0],size[1],size[2],0);
    ctx.lineWidth= 2;
    grad.addColorStop(0, 'green');
    grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'green');
    grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'yellow');
    grad.addColorStop(0.8, 'yellow');
    grad.addColorStop(0.8, 'red');
    grad.addColorStop(1, 'red');
    ctx.fillStyle = grad;   
    ctx.fillRect(size[0], size[1], size[2], size[3]);


    ctx.translate(0, canvasHeight/2);
    ctx.strokeStyle= "black";

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(canvasWidth*0.5, -6);
    ctx.lineTo(canvasWidth*0.5, 6);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(canvasWidth*0.8, -6);
    ctx.lineTo(canvasWidth*0.8, 6);
    ctx.stroke();
});
```

The code is also in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0nqLqdhd/)

As you can see I create 3 color sections using the createLinearGradient method, I add stops at 0.5 and 0.8, then I try to plot ticks at those same spaces. The ticks are dislocated to the left a few pixels and I have no idea why. This is only noticeable in big gradients, in small gradients (like 300px x 300px) the ticks appear to be in the right position.

Note: I have to use linear gradients, changing to simple colored rectangles is not an option. I want to be able to define gradients as well as solid colors sections with the same code (just changing the color stops).

Comment: I confirm your findings. BTW, the undesired offset is different in different browsers.  I would say the undesired offset depends on the use of percentages in the color stop versus the user of  pixel coordinates in line drawings.  I can't think of a way to reconcile the variance and make the gradient & lines align. :-/

Comment: @markE I tested in Opera 12 (presto engine) and firefox and it seems to be okay, it seems this is a webkit/blnk bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a webkit specific bug. The fiddle renders correctly in Firefox, IE11 and Opera 12 (presto engine). I filled a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=414254) to chromium.